# Set Height of li using simple CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a model using ul li what I need is
[image]

and I'm getting something like

[image]

the problem here I'm facing is the height of li, there is no height above the first row and below the last row in first image but I'm getting it into 2nd image, my code is

```
<ul class="appul">
  <li>08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>.....</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.appul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .appul li {
        border-right: 2px solid #CCC;
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 15.6px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    .appul li:nth-child(5n) {
        border-right: none;
    }
    .appul li a {
        color: #00c8cf;
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .appul li a:hover {
        color: #00c8cf;
    }
```

Comment: @fcalderan, that question did not solve my problem, that's why I'm asking with images as well

Comment: ok. I'll reopen then.

Comment: How are you placing the additional values under your `li` ?

Comment: @KashifLatif do you have to use line-height property?

Comment: Is it 1 big `ul` or can it be divided into rows as I did in my answer?

Comment: @Chris I'm using line-height just for testing, it's not mandatory

Comment: @LGSon it's one big `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Here is used `padding` instead of `line-height` to achieve a distance between the time items, where I set a main top padding on all and the removed it again for the first 5.

```css
.appul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.appul:before,
.appul:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-color: #CCC;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;   /* Alt. 1: let mouse event pass through   */
  z-index: -1;            /* Alt. 2: put pseudo elements beneath    */
}
.appul:after {
  left: 60%;
}

.appul li {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.appul li:nth-child(-n+5) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.appul li a:hover {
  color: #00c8cf;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="appul">
  <li>08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>08:45</li>
  <li>09:00</li>
  <li>09:15</li>
  <li>09:30</li>
  <li>09:45</li>
  <li>10:00</li>
  <li>10:15</li>
  <li>10:30</li>
  <li>10:45</li>
</ul>
```

If you do want to change column length to less or more than 5, this variant could be useful

```css
.appul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: calc(20% + 4px) 100%;
  background-position: calc(25% - 4px) 100%;
}
.appul li {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.appul li:nth-child(-n+5) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.appul li a:hover {
  color: #00c8cf;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="appul">
  <li>08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>08:45</li>
  <li>09:00</li>
  <li>09:15</li>
  <li>09:30</li>
  <li>09:45</li>
  <li>10:00</li>
  <li>10:15</li>
  <li>10:30</li>
  <li>10:45</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No idea but why have you broken the list into pieces...?

Comment: @Paulie_D It appears to be 5 in each row .. but of course, the underlying code could be 1 big `ul`, which makes my solution not work so well anymore. .. I will ask OP and if so, delete (or change to another solution)

Comment: @Paulie_D Updated my answer .. better ? ;)

Comment: @KashifLatif Need to run now, but will be back in an hour ... do you want the gray lines to go all the way even if there are no more time items?

Comment: yup i want that gray line till the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103069/discussion-between-kashif-latif-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0):

It is very critical to achieve design like this using ul li. But, if you are able to add remaining empty li elements in the last row then do check this fiddle link

`fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/SolaceInfotech/y91rosyu/`

that might help you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: still getting issue with border

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you don't need to use `line-height` here...just adjust the respective paddings.

Also a `box-sizing` would be useful.

Finally...there is no such thing as .6 of a pixel. Use integers for that as  different browsers may round differently.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.appul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.appul li {
  border-right: 2px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
  /* for demo only */
  float: left;
  padding: 0 24px 36px;
}
.appul li:nth-child(5n) {
  border-right: none;
}
.appul li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
.appul li a {
  color: #00c8cf;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.appul li a:hover {
  color: #00c8cf;
}
```

```html
<ul class="appul">
  <li>08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>08:45</li>
  <li>09:00</li>
  <li>09:15</li>
  <li>09:30</li>
  <li>09:45</li>
  <li>10:00</li>
  <li>10:15</li>
  <li>10:30</li>
  <li>10:45</li>
  <li>10:30</li>
  <li>10:45</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/dpyjbqjv/

html:

```
<ul class="appul">
  <li class="first-row">08:00</li>
  <li class="first-row">08:15</li>
  <li class="first-row">08:30</li>
  <li class="first-row">08:30</li>
  <li class="first-row">08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>08:30</li>
  <li>08:00</li>
  <li>08:15</li>
  <li class="last-row">08:30</li>
  <li class="last-row">08:30</li>
  <li class="last-row">08:30</li>
  <li class="last-row">08:30</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.appul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 400px;
}

.appul li {
  border-right: 2px solid #CCC;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.appul li:nth-child(5n) {
  border-right: none;
}

.appul li.first-row {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.appul li.last-row {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```